# setting Heroku env through app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I know how to set Heroku env by using

```
Heroku config:set hello=world
```

but what if inside my Heroku rails app (I'm admin), I want to set this variables without going in Heroku command-line, but through code. How can I do this?
I probably need some code like this:

```
def set_world
  Heroku::Config[:hello] = 'world'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that environment variable for the lifetime of the current process, you can just do:

```
ENV['hello'] = 'world'
```

That is definitely not advisable though, as it won't work on multiple dynos, nor will it work if you're using a fork-based webserver, like unicorn.

You can add/update configuration parameters on an application using the [platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars).

So issuing a PATH request to the heroku API at the URL `/apps/{app_id_or_name}/config-vars` with the changes you wich to make will update the environment variables.
Updating the config variables restarts your application though. So you might want to take care and avoid doing that too much.

Comment: I need it so that if I go back into Heroku config I will actually see the change setting.

Comment: So you need to make calls to the API.

Comment: Yes. I would need heroku api with that

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'heroku-api'
heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => 'your api key')
heroku.put_config_vars('your app name', 'your env key' => 'the value')
```